# Reference Question for Soldered Breadboard/Perfboard

Tags: discussion

I have seen some horrible soldered breadboards recently. And it wasn't just the soldering, the entire approach was bad. For a recent question, I was going to post pictures of my built circuit, but it seems that the OP has abandoned the post. Then I thought that this could be a reference question that people can point to in the future.

I searched this site and didn't find anything relevant.

Would it be appropriate to ask a question like this and answer it myself? It is opinion based, so this is a gray area. But it is something that many beginners badly need.

*How should I wire my circuit onto a perfboard?*

My answer will show how I typically build simple circuits with thru-hole parts. Others can add their own examples. I would like to limit the scope to fairly low-speed circuits. High-speed digital and RF is too complicated for beginners anyway.

Question: Is this acceptable? Or is there another way to word this so it won't be closed immediately?

FYI: Here is a link to the post that motivated me to create a build tutorial. If a general reference question is not acceptable, I will add my build tutorial to this answer. [Astable Multivibrator Not Oscillating](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/690285/astable-multivibrator-not-oscillating)

Done: Q/A is here: [How should I wire my circuit onto a perfboard?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/690705/how-should-i-wire-my-circuit-onto-a-perfboard/690706#690706)

Comment: Mattman944 - Hi, In case I don't get back to post an actual answer here, I suggest having a read of [this](/q/7518) Meta question which was asked about whether or not another opinion-based question was likely to be suitable or not. I explained my thoughts in that case, in an answer there. || As you see by what I linked & quoted there, questions containing *some* opinion can still have value IMHO - with some caveats. I know there are some Q&A about self-answered questions over at [meta.se] too. || I think it's important to pose any self-answered question as a genuine question {...}

Comment: {...} to give others a fair chance at answering too (and you've already said that). I haven't decided what seems fair about accepting an answer (or not) e.g. what if yours is the only answer after *n* days? Should you accept it & likely dissuade others from posting answers later? Or not accept it? What if others post good answers but you still think yours is best. Do you accept another answer just to *not* be seen to be accepting yours? I don't pretend to have answers to these points, but I wanted to give you some things to consider, in case I don't get back to post an answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @SamGibson - I wasn't planning on accepting any answer.

Comment: Mattman944 - Re: "I wasn't planning on accepting any answer" - Which raises a different problem, as *that* approach may dissuade those people who are extremely motivated by the "points"! But you've been up-front that this is your plan and I see you have now posted the question. Good luck!

Comment: If only the definitions for "breadboard," "stripboard," "perfboard," "protoboard," etc. were consistent across geography and time... "Soldered breadboard" to me implies trying to solder one of those prototyping devices that are mostly plastic with embedded metal contacts to grip through-hole component leads.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this type of question is acceptable and on topic and the kind of questions that stack exchange wishes to create. Stack exchange also allows for self answering of questions (you don't get the rep however) I couldn't find the original question, feel free to create another one if you can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

While there are infinitely many possible answers, there are a few common and good answers to such a topic, and they can be objectively justified.  I would upvote such a question, and might even consider adding an answer myself!

From the [Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/),[1] good questions have enduring answers -- it's not even a problem to ask for products, as long as they're likely to be around for a long time, or, much better still -- *how to find kinds of products*, rather than specific makes and models.

In our case, protoboards of all manner have been around for decades, and have every reason to continue for decades onward, so this seems a good topic to me.

[1] At least, give or take the date of this post; I'm unclear whether these posts should be taken as current precedent, or what hierarchical scoping should be applied to Stack vs. SU vs. EESE, or if anything should be considered as superseding opinion since these posts.